# Apply class & ng-class both

Tags: angularjs

I am new to this. I have following html.

My `ng-class` value comes to `active`. so both these classes should be applied i.e. `cardHeader` and `active`.

But `active` class doesn't get applied.

```
<div class="cardHeader" ng-class="{{practice.status}}">{{practice.name}}</div>
```

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-class` takes an object, not an angular expression

```
<div class="cardHeader" ng-class="{active: practice.status == 'active'}">{{practice.name}}</div>
```

or this should also work

```
<div class="cardHeader {{practice.status}}">{{practice.name}}</div>
```

Comment: One can pass an array to `ng-class` as well: `ng-class={{ [practise.status] }}` should also work.